# How to quickly tell if a Magento site is version 1.x or 2.x?

Tags: magento2, magento-1

While browsing some sites that built on Magento, how do you tell if it based on 1.x or 2.x.

I do have Built-with extension in Chrome, but prefer manual approach.

Thanks!

Comment: View source on any stock CSS or JavaScript. The copyright notice leaks this info like a seive.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

View the page source can check the CSS location.

**Magento 1** css file is located here:

> mainfolder/skin/frontend/spacename/themename/css/css files

**Magento 2** css file is located here:

> mainfolder/pub/static/frontend/spacename/themename/locale/css/css
>   files

Answer (score 3):

**Clues for Magento 1.x:**

1. In page source, there should be words like:

   - varien
   - skin/frontend
   - media
2. When trying to hit URL **`[website_url]/downloader`**, it should show **Magento Connect** page (if downloader has not been removed/renamed)
3. When trying to hit URL **`[website_url]/install.php`**, it should show error:

   - FAILED ERROR: Magento is already installed
4. Default URL for contact us page is **`[website_url]/contacts`** in Magento 1.x

**Clues for Magento 2.x:**

1. In page source, there should be words like:

   - pub/static/frontend
2. Default URL for contact us page is **`[website_url]/contact`** in Magento 2.x
3. When trying to hit URL **`[website_url]/magento_version`**, it should show Magento's major version and edition like:

   - Magento/2.x (xxx)

**Note:** One more way to check Magento version is check website in https://www.magereport.com/ under **`Outdated Magento version`** section.

I hope, it would be more clear now.

Comment: Great and Acceptable Answer:)

Answer (score 2):

Also, adding one more way to check if the website is in Magento 1.x or Magento 2.X.

**Magento 2: Mage cookies script tag will be as follows:**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "mage/cookies": {
                "expires": null,
                "path": "/",
                "domain": ".www.example.com",
                "secure": false,
                "lifetime": "3600"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Magento 1 : Mage cookies script tag will be as follows:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Mage.Cookies.path     = '/';
Mage.Cookies.domain   = '.example.com';
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check it using page view source,
At top display require js declaration like,

```
<script>
    var require = {
        "baseUrl": "{{project url}}/pub/static/frontend/{Packagename}/{theme}/en_US"
    };
```

Also you can check it using searching `pub/static/frontend/` path for js and css file.

Another way is default magento contact us page,
in Magento 1, contact-us link is display , `www.projectname.com/contacts`
where magento 2, contacts link is `www.projectname.com/contact`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check with https://builtwith.com/. In `Ecommerce` section it shows Magento if the site is built in Magento.

- If it is Magento 1 site, `Ecommerce` section shows `Magento` only.
- If it is Magento 2 site, `Ecommerce` section shows `Magento 2` inside `Magento` section.
- It also mentions if it is a `Magento Enterprise` edition.

Answer (score 0):

View the source and search for any of these terms:

```
text/x-magento-init
getTemplate()
Magento_Ui/js/core/app
```

If you find them, it's Magento 2!

Answer (score 0):

You can also add to the end of the url "**/magento_version**", this show only for Magento 2 , the version it uses.

**Request:**

`http://<magento2-store>/magento_version`

**Response:**

`Magento/2.3 (Community)`

More info [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/versioning/check-version.html)

Answer (score 0):

View the page source and inspect the CSS files location (Right click >> View Page Source).
Most of the .css files are located in file path like this:

1. Magento 1 css files are located like here:

   **domain_name/skin/...**

example:

```
www.mysite.com/skin/frontend/myshop/myshop_theme/css/main_style.css
```

2. Magento 2 css files are located like here:

   **domain_name/static/**

example:

```
www.mysite.com/static/frontend/myshop/myshop_theme/en_US/css/style_name.css
```

Extra tip: Use `Ctrl+F >> .css >> Enter` to search for all .css files in page source.