# Upgraded Magento and now Admin page is blank

Tags: admin, upgrade

I've just updated our store as it hadn't been done in a while through Magento Connect.

Now when I try to access the admin area (http://www.example.com/index.php/admin) it just returns a white page.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

I believe it's Magento 1.9 but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: First check the version of Magento, so that it is easy to identify. To know Magento version, please check this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110453/how-to-quickly-tell-if-a-magento-site-is-version-1-x-or-2-x/193053#193053

Comment: I would start by flushing cache manually , id also probably rename includes folder to includesbak and then check any errors

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling compilation to start if the compilation was not disabled before upgrade the compiled files may have become out of sync with the Magento Version you are now currently on.

> **1. Disable Compilation**

**Shell Method**

```
php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable
```

Run above command from root magento directory if you have ssh access.

**OR**

**Via FTP**

Rename the folder to includesbak or comment out the 2 lines within  includes/config.php which should also disable compilation.

> **2. Clear Cache**

```
rm -rf var/cache
```

Run above command from magento root or delete folder with ftp.

> **3. Check errors**

Add below to index.php to show errors this may further help us rather than just guessing.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

You can also check **var/log/system.log** and other log files within **var/log** folder for errors. Check what errors show up when you visit admin. If none of the above fix the issue then add some errors to your question found in these logs and we may have more hope figuring the real cause.

I would also recommend atleast moving that admin url to something custom to your store.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

1 - Compilation was already disabled.

2 - Have cleared cache which hasn't helped.

3 - I added that line in index.php but there are still no errors showing and var/log doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: No worries let me know how it goes i had this happen once before.

Comment: Maybe try reset permissions:
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;     
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;     
find ./media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;   
chmod 777 ./app/etc              
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Comment: Make sure you have the new /app/design/adminhtml folder - I've upgraded via Magento Shell before and this folder was totally missing.

Comment: I've reset the permissions and still no luck. @RickyOdinMatthews the folder is there and has content.

Comment: Are errors starting to show now in var/log? Maybe start by checking errors in apche logs if not /var/log/apache2/error.log might be location that is from root of server not magento

Comment: @harri I still don't seem to have a /var/log directory?